# How to rotate a grid in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

In my WP7 application i want to rotate a grid with some degrees. Is it possible to rotate reversely when the page orientation is changed.Please help me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635515.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate the grid

```
 <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform Rotation="180"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also rotate it in the design area by clicking on the corner and the rotating once you get the bent arrow symbol.